# How to show hash (#) before extension in libphonenumber?

Tags: phone-number, libphonenumber

I would like to generate number with a hash (#) to produce number that can be dialed with extension.

How to do this?

I have following code:

```
    PhoneNumberUtil phoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
    Iterable<PhoneNumberMatch> matches = phoneNumberUtil.findNumbers("0730506760 int 120", "RO");

    for(PhoneNumberMatch match: matches){
        PhoneNumber number = match.number();
        System.out.println(phoneNumberUtil.format(number, PhoneNumberFormat.E164) );
        System.out.println(phoneNumberUtil.format(number, PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL) );
        System.out.println(phoneNumberUtil.format(number, PhoneNumberFormat.NATIONAL) );
        System.out.println(phoneNumberUtil.format(number, PhoneNumberFormat.RFC3966) );
        System.out.println(phoneNumberUtil.formatOutOfCountryCallingNumber(number, "GB") );
        System.out.println(phoneNumberUtil.formatOutOfCountryCallingNumber(number, "US"));

    }
```

Which produces:

```
+40730506760
+40 730 506 760 int 120
0730 506 760 int 120
tel:+40-730-506-760;ext=120
00 40 730 506 760 int 120
011 40 730 506 760 int 120
```

What I want:

```
+40730506760#120
```

Does anyone knows how should I format this number to achieve desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way I see would be a workaround. Use `System.out.println(phoneNumberUtil.format(number, PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL) );` and replace spaces by "" and "int" by "#".